# issues with setting up proxy between apache server and tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxy, virtualhost, reverse-proxy

I have been trying to set up a web proxy to redirect to the tomcat app which is located at

http://example.com:8085/app . But I am not able to get it to work.

```
<VirtualHost XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:80>
    ServerName example.com

    ServerAlias www.example.com

    ProxyRequests Off

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass /app http://localhost:8085/app
    ProxyPassReverse /app http://localhost:8085/app

    #ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8085/ (tried this as well)
    #ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8085/ (tried this as well)

    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>

    #DocumentRoot /home/groupname/public_html (apache location - dummy)

    DocumentRoot /usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-6.0.33/webapps/app (tomcat location)

</VirtualHost>
```

Following is the configuration from the server.xml file.

```
    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

    <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
    unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
    xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

<Connector port="8085" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

Now this is what I am trying to do. When I type www.example.com or example.com I want to go to the app. Can someone give me pointers as to that I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need mod_jk or something similar to do the real connection between tomcat and apache.

Try [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/quick.html)

The proxy settings up there is more aimed for hiding the port number

Comment: mod_jk is one way of doing it. I have got mod_proxy set up on my server so was trying to get it work before I go ahead and try mod_jk.

Comment: well, if that's the case, the ajp connector is not relevant here. as for proxy `<Connector port="8085" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" />`. The right syntax should be `proxyport` according to [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/proxy-howto.html)